Could a biological organism power itself with electricity like a smartphone (or something similar)?
Imagine an alien world where there are are shallow lakes where electricity generating beings (like electric eels or whatever) would power many of the land dwelling creatures, including the dominant inteligent species (before they invent machines that would do that). They would go inside a lake and "charge themselves" like a smartphone or other things that we use on Earth.
Because of this those aliens would be more gentle (they wouldn't need that much food) and would probably enter their version of "Industrial revolution" much sooner than other species (since they used electricity since the begining).
I initially had an idea that giant exotic trees could have microorganisms inside them that generated electricity (they could have giant holes like Sequoia trees) and aliens would go inside and "charge".
Ideally,those beings wouldnt need to eat at all,and recieved all energy they need from electricity and drinking water (or some other solvent). Feel free to sugest something that sounds more realistic/better for you.

while biological energy is a thing and is how our brain transmits signals i think the issue is a little more complicated. You can't just store electricity as it's just an energy exchange. You need to convert the electricity in chemical energy first for that to work so your creatures need an organ that functions as a sort battery. Another matter is how the actually get the electricity from entering their body while keeping it from interfering with their muscles and such. It is also a very niche trait that would wipe them out if their resource is gone. So it's hard to evolve naturally.

So world of parasites consuming electricity?  This requires for the parasites to trigger electrical generation mode of the plants.because why would plants just bleed out electrical energy?

Actually, they do. A byproduct of photosynthesis is some electric charge; you can actually use leaves as a low-energy power source, assuming they’re in bright sunlight and the leaves are big enough. Plants can’t use the spare electrons anyway.

I believe the primary issue is that some form of non energy nutrient is still needed. A typical creature has physical structure, comprised of various cells, maintained and allowed to grow by nutrients like vitamins and proteins. Perhaps some sort of robot that, through sci-fi wonder metal needs no maintenance? Or the water is rich in algae and plankton, allowing them to filter feed? Those are the options I can think of, sorry if it was unhelpful.
